# Re-triggering animate.css animation on change of slide in Siema.js Carousel

Tags: jquery, css, animation, animate.css

I have already done quite a bit of research on this but have yet to find a good specific answer that would be scalable and pertains to the combination of libraries I am using in my project (animate.css, siema.js).

I am essentially trying to make an element on any given slide initiate every time the slide has come into view. [Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akinhwan/ndLnphqy/1/)

External resources for the fiddle include animate.css and siema.js
Note that for the first revolution through the three slides (which are all just duplicates) the animation for the green cards works. But this is a rudimentary solution that is achieved on {animation-duration: x} and based on the duration of the slides and transition speed.

WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE:
Make the animations trigger beyond just the first revolution (in the jsfiddle they are on infinite loop after the three slides are shown for the first time). The animations should ONLY occur when the slide has stopped and moved into full screen view. Then the animations should stop while other slides are being viewed.
Make the animations trigger in a programmatic way that can adapt to different slide intervals, number of slides, and slide animation types/times.

THINGS I"VE TRIED:
I could change the @keyframe for the animations to make them have a built in delay, but this would not be programmatic and would have to be re-done for every addition or subtraction of new slides, or if I were to change the duration of the slide in any way.

I have also tried simultaneously removing and adding the animate.css class to the elements I want animated on slide change using both jQuery and the Siema.js API (mySiema.currentSlide, and Siema.onChange). This I am convinced is probably closer to the right way of doing this but have been unsuccessful.

Below I am inserting only the js i am using for the fiddle because stackoverflow is saying i can't link to jsfiddle unless i paste code in the question...?

```
    var mySiema = new Siema({
      selector: siema,
      duration: 2000,
      easing: 'ease-out',
      perPage: 1,
      startIndex: 0,
      loop: true,
      onInit: () => {},
      onChange: applyAnimation
    });

    setInterval(() => mySiema.next(), 4000)
```